# Can you use jsx within template string in React render props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Is it possible to put JSX inside a template string that is being used as a React render prop?

This is what I'm trying to do, but it leads to the link rendering as `[object Object]`

```
const Container = ({ message }) => <div className="from line 4"> {message}</div>;
const Link = () => <a href="#">juan</a>;

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Container message={`My message with a ${<Link />}`} />
  </div>
);
```

One thing I tried was to put JSX instead of a template string inside `message`. This works, but it introduces a new `div` that isn't needed.

```
<Container
  message={<div>My message {<Link />}</div>}
/>
```

I made this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1y83mxj64l) to illustrate the problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) to render inline like you are trying to do and to prevent adding a new wrapping `<div />`:

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <Container
      message={<React.Fragment>My message with a <Link /></React.Fragment>}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Here is a forked version of your Codesandbox using `React.Fragment`: https://codesandbox.io/s/nrmr9l34vl